# MVC Code-First Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, migration

I need to **create table Drivers with multiple unique index**,
why I'm see this message and, how I can solve this? plz help me.

Problem is I cant do update-database on migrations

Message Error is :

> Column 'Phone' in table 'dbo.Drivers' is of a type that is invalid for
>   use as a key column in an index

```
public class Driver
    {
        public int DriverID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Code { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Index("PhoneAndIdentAndDLExpAndVRNo", Order =1)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public int Gender { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Index("PhoneAndIdentAndDLExpAndVRNo", Order = 2)]
        public string Ident { get; set; }
        [Index("PhoneAndIdentAndDLExpAndVRNo", Order = 3)]
        public string DLNo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime DLExp { get; set; }
        [Index("PhoneAndIdentAndDLExpAndVRNo", Order = 4)]
        public string VRNo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime VRExp { get; set; }

        public string CarType { get; set; }
        public string CarColor { get; set; }
        public string CarModel { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool IsOnline { get; set; }
        public string TokenID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Pwd { get; set; }

    }
```

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeCYC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max length for an index column is 900 bytes. The fix is as simple as below.

```
 [MaxLength(20)]
 [Index("PhoneAndIdentAndDLExpAndVRNo", Order =1)]
 public string Phone { get; set; }
```